# What's the proper way to establish a triaxial connection with carabiners?

Tags: safety, climbing, climbing-anchors, carabiners

I love free climbing but have never climbed with ropes. While reading through [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1384/what-does-it-mean-to-cross-load-a-carabiner), I realized I would never have thought of these scenarios, but due to the answers on that post, the physics in question makes sense. But this left me with a question:

**How would one achieve a triaxial connection if loading a carabiner in this way is dangerous?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want one point and multiple things to connect to it, then what you do is create a master point with rope or cordellete and attach your carabiners to it.

Usually the master point is a a overhand knot on a bight and the carabiners attach to the loop.

That looks like this,

[image]

[Image Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mountain_climbing_equipment_in_Mirabad_-_Nishapur_01.JPG)

In the other situation mentioned in the linked question where the sling goes around the tree, one would use a longer sling to go around the tree and then hook a carabiner to just one loop.

Comment: The answer is correct and good, but the picture is not very clear for nyone not familiar with all the gear. Perhaps a pic with a simpler setup (and no rigging plate involved, that is a specialty item)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a triple butterfly knot, some call them *alpine butterfly loop knots* or simply *multi-loop knots*. They can be tied with single loops, double loops, and triple loops. No collection/rigging plate needed and simple to tie.

[image]

photo courtesy of dave@Layhands.com